# ResponsiveVoice JS not working for the string with new line

Tags: responsivevoice

Hi ResponsiveVoice js is not working when I process a paragraph with new lines.

Say I have a text file with below string-

```
Pitch, rate and volume may not affect audio on some browser combinations, older versions of Chrome on Windows for example.
```

Then it is working fine but if use enter butten for new line and text file have below string-

```
    Pitch, rate and volume may not affect audio on 
some browser combinations, older versions of Chrome on Windows for example.
```

Now in above string I added a new line after 'audio on' and when I process above string then no audio file will be generated.
Please let me know how I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

We just released ResponsiveVoice 1.4.1 which should fix the issue. Please let us know if it doesn't!

http://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js